# vb.net database Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: vb.net

i have a database with 16 fields and i just want to fill the first 7 fields.
i am using this command

```
"INSERT INTO products (SupplierID, catalogid, ccode,cname,oprice,cprice,pother2) VALUES (" & reader("SupplierID").ToString() & "," & reader("catalogid").ToString() & "," & reader("ccode").ToString() & "," & reader("cname").ToString() & "," & reader("oprice").ToString() & "," & reader("cprice").ToString() & "," & reader("pother2").ToString() & ")"
```

so any solutions?

Comment: cname is a string correct? Are you wrapping it in single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with only filling a subset of the available fields in a table as long as the columns that you are not filling are specified as nullable or have a default assigned (assuming SQL server).

However, there is something wrong with the way that you are building your command: you do not have quotes around what appear to be string values (i.e. ccname) nor are you safeguarding against SQL injection attacks.

It is much better to use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx).

Roughly, your code would look something like:

```
Dim oCommand As New SqlCommand()

oCommand.Connection = oConnection

oCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO products (SupplierID, catalogid, ccode,cname,oprice,cprice,pother2) VALUES ("?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

oCommand.Parameters(0).Value = reader("SupplierID")
oCommand.Parameters(0).Value = reader("catalogid")

etc...
```

Comment: its just a simple vb.net application and its using an offline access database ,SupplierID, catalogid, ccode,cname,oprice,cprice,pother2 are the column names isnt it this the right way to specify colmun names?

Comment: He means the values. String values need to be wrapped in single quotes, not the column names.

Comment: Integer values do not need to be wrapped in single quotes. As stated though, you should look into using parameterized queries to avoid these sorts of issues when manually building queries.. as well as preventing SQL injection..

Comment: whait i want to do is to copy values that doesnt exist from database 1 to database2

Comment: Even in an access database, if you have a string value that you are using in dynamic SQL, not only do you have to wrap it in quotes, you also have to "double-up" any quotes within the string value itself in order to prevent invalid SQL. Using parameters makes it much, much easier to deal with (in addition to the added security benefirts).